# How to only return 1 when the case is True?

Tags: python, boolean

I want my code to be as 'pythonic" as possible, so I tried minimizing it. I want it to print 1 when the input is leap year, and 0 when it's not.

The code below prints out 1 and 0 properly.

```
a = input()
if int(1 and not a%4 and a%100 or not a%400):
    print 1
else:
    print 0
```

While this code prints out something very odd. It works fine but doesn't print out 'only' 1 for leap years.

```
a = input()
print int(1 and not a%4 and a%100 or not a%400)
```

For example, it will print out 4 for 4 and 12 for 12, which is true, yet not what I want. Is there a way to fix the code so it prints out only 1 for true cases without writing more lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can minimize such sections like this:

```
 a = input()
 print 1 if int(1 and not a % 4 and a % 100 or not a % 400) else 0
```

For leap-years, your `if` condition will not always evaluate to 1, but to something `> 0`, which is regarded as `True` in Python.

Answer (score 4):

Why reinvent the wheel?  This functionality is already available via [`calendar.isleap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap):

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.isleap(2000)
True
>>> calendar.isleap(2001)
False
>>>
```

To make these results into explicit integers, simply use `int`:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> int(calendar.isleap(2000))
1
>>> int(calendar.isleap(2001))
0
>>>
```

Comment: AHhahaha I was practicing algorithms and stuff :p

Comment: Well, if you are doing it for fun or to learn, then that is fine.  But otherwise I would strongly encourage you to use `calendar.isleap`.  Handcrafting date algorithms is tricky, time-consuming, and rarely done right.  Your code will be a lot more robust (and cleaner) using the extensively tested date tools in the Python standard library.

Answer (score 2):

`and` and `or` are coalescing; they will return one of their operands. So we need to turn that value into a `bool`:

```
return bool(not a%4 and a%100 or not a%400)
```

And `bool` is a subset of `int` so we can use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

The code is actually quite the opposite:

```
int(((not a%4 and a%100) or not a%400) != 0)
```

Because `and` binds tighter than `or` you can even drop the closest pair of brackets:

```
int((not a%4 and a%100 or not a%400) != 0)
```

A year is a leap year if it is

> Dividable by `4` and not by `100`, **or** dividable by `400`.

Comment: Oh, I guess the '1 and' part was the problem. That made me swap the boolean cases to match it into test cases. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I just tried out your code, and it does the exact same thing as mine... and it prints out something other than 1.

Comment: @JosephSeungJaeDollar: fixed I guess?

Comment: Your brackets are unbalanced (there's an unmatched `)` in each snippet).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def is_leap_year(year):
  return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

print int(is_leap_year(1999))  # 0
print int(is_leap_year(2000))  # 1
print int(is_leap_year(2004))  # 1
print int(is_leap_year(2100))  # 0
print int(is_leap_year(2400))  # 1
```

Comment: You can optimize this by "grouping" results together using bitwise `and` and `or`.

Comment: @CommuSoft: How is that an "optimization"?

Comment: Do I have to use a method and return something?

Comment: @CommuSoft: What makes you think this is even relevant? Also, bitwise operators don't short-circuit.

Comment: @NPE: It is relevant because as in Haskell, most Pythonians want to write shorter code. You thus drop 8 characters ;).

Answer (score 0):

Programming is communication. Regardless of the language, the best code is that which is correct, efficient, and easy to understand. Complex boolean expressions are awful, and should be avoided. It's simpler (and often more efficient) to code in early-exit style:

```
def is_leap(y):
    if y % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if y % 100 == 0:
        return False
    return y % 4 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

### On 'Pythonic'

First things first...  While 'pythonic' is a somewhat ambiguous term, I think the code in question is unlikely to be considered 'pythonic' (or perhaps 'idiomatic python' or 'written using commonly accepted python idioms').

One-liner/minimized code is generally not what 'being pythonic' is about - readability concerns are more important, so splitting code into multiple lines is preferable if it makes the code easier to read and reason about.  Of course, if there are built-ins or standard library functions that do something in one line that you would otherwise have to write in several lines, that's probably 'pythonic'. (e.g. use calendar.isleap for actual code).

To get a feel of what set of values are often considered 'pythonic', run `import this` on your python interpreter.

With that disclaimer out of the way...

### Breaking down this code

In this particular case, having a `w and x and y or z` inside an int() function, then using that as a boolean condition is likely to be frowned upon, because it's difficult to see what precisely is happening.  Don't do this in production code...

So what really *is* happening with `int(1 and not a%4 and a%100 or not a%400)`?

First things first, chaining Boolean operators without parentheses is always a bit scary, so let's figure out how it's being evaluated.  According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), the above becomes

```
int( (1 and (not a%4) and a%100) or (not a%400) )
```

Your code takes the form `int(A or B)`, with `A` further taking the form of `X and Y and Z`.

Now let's look at the [docs for boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

You find that **and** evaluates every item from left to right, and return either False upon finding the first False value, or evaluates to the right-most value and returns that value.

So for `1 and not a%4 and a%100` to be `True`, all three elements must be `True` or non-zero, and then the returned value is the right-most element which is `a%100`.
So when you run:

```
>>> a = 4
>>> print int(1 and not a%4 and a%100 or not a%400)
4
```

The `4` is the result of `a%100`.

```
>>> a = 4
>>> print int(1 and not a%4 and a%100 or not a%400)
#             ^        ^          ^         ^
#             |        |          |         |
#           True     True         4       False (but this isn't even evaluated because of the nature of or)
```

### Possible One-Liner Solutions

If you really want a one-liner that returns 1 if `a` is a leap year and 0 otherwise, here it is:

```
print int(not a%4 and a%100 and 1 or not a%400)
```

By putting the `and 1` at the right-most end of the **and** chain, this gets evaluated after a%100, and so will override whatever integer value a%100 has.  Or alternatively:

```
print int(bool(not a%4 and a%100 or not a%400))
```

I'm just coercing the condition to a Boolean first (i.e. strictly a True/False value), then coerce it back to an integer which will strictly take the form of 1/0.

I like this marginally better because the casting to Boolean and recasting to int is explicit, and am not relying on the **and** evaluation order.  But only marginally.  Better not to do the one-liner.

### Better Solutions

[@icodez's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27725386/3155195) is what you want to use in production code.

[@lee-daniel-crocker's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27726149/3155195) is what it should look like if you were to insist on writing one yourself.  btw I think this has the good property of actually returning True/False values rather than 1/0.  That's definitely more idiomatic python.